# Why does Egit (Eclipse Git integration) not work in 3.8?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, egit

I've installed EGit in Eclipse 3.8 (which I got via the Ubuntu 16.04 repositories).

I could install EGit without a problem, but I cannot open the Git perspective.

What can I do to track down the problem?

Comment: Eclipse 3.8 has been released almost six years ago in June 2012. Please install Eclipse Oxygen.3a (4.7.3a) which already contains EGit.

Comment: The versions of Eclipse packaged with Ubuntu are ancient, get a modern version from the official Eclipse site https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/

Comment: is there a repo i can add to ubuntu? or do i have to use the 'portable' version?

Comment: Not sure if this is still valid: https://itsfoss.com/install-latest-eclipse-ubuntu/